# PhpSpreadsheet: two table in a sheet and two autofilter

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

i am using phpspreadsheet. I have two tables in the same spreadsheet and in both tables I would like to add the autofilter, but it takes into account only the last one added.
Example:

```
//table 1 code
...
...
//autofilter 1
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:E1');

//Table 2 code
...
...
//autofilter 2 
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('G1:K1');
```

output: autofilter only from G1 to K1, and not from A1 to E1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think is a limitation, only the last setAutoFilter() function call is evaluated, even on the same sheet.
I think I'll open a bug report.